# Why the replace function in PostgreSQL is not returning the value?

Tags: postgresql, database, replace

I am trying to convert state names to abbreviations and I am using the replace function. I am able to run the snippet successfully but names remain the same without being converted to abbreviation:

```
UPDATE county SET state_name = replace(state_name, '(Texas)', 'TX');
UPDATE county SET state_name = replace(state_name, '(Utah)', 'UT');
UPDATE county SET state_name = replace(state_name, '(Vermont)', 'VT');
UPDATE county SET state_name = replace(state_name, '(Virginia)', 'VA');
UPDATE county SET state_name = replace(state_name, '(Washington)', 'WA');
UPDATE county SET state_name = replace(state_name, '(West Virginia)', 'WV');
UPDATE county SET state_name = replace(state_name, '(Wisconsin)', 'WI');
UPDATE county SET state_name = replace(state_name, '(Wyoming)', 'WY');
UPDATE county SET state_name = replace(state_name, '(Puerto Rico)', 'PR');

--Let's check the result
select * from county;
```

[image]

Comment: Please remember to always place code as text in a code block within the body of the question. This makes it legible on all devices and permits the volunteers who would help you to try their own solutions without each first copying the text from an image. It is unclear that this is a GIS question. It may be more appropriate in [dba.se].

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am going to put the code as text and change the tag

Comment: what does `select replace('flimflam (Texas) blahblah', '(Texas)', 'TX') as state` return?

Comment: @PaulH  that returns "flimflam TX blahblah", so I guess we need to know what is in state_name

Comment: I agree with @IanTurton....I'm betting `state_name` has leading and/or trailing whitespace, or it's in capital letters, or for whatever reason the pattern is just not what OP is expecting. ....hopefully, whatever it is, it's systematic!

Comment: OP, you might try formatting like this, which removes leading and trailing spaces, and compares against uppercase letters only, to see if it comes to life: `REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(state_name))), UPPER('(Puerto Rico)'), 'PR')`

Comment: I just added a picture to make it more clear. The code works giving me a successful application message but as you can see in the picture when I check for the result the variable state_name is intact.

Comment: oh.... OP, remove the '(' and the ')' from the second argument in your `replace()` function. That's breaking the comparison.

Comment: :( .... Did not work

Comment: Let me try the other solution you have suggested in the comments (LTRIM)

Comment: You still have to remove the `(` and the `)` from your second argument. I guarantee it will not match with those characters.

Comment: Thank you so much @elrobis it finally worked. The code is: `UPDATE county SET state_name = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(state_name))), UPPER('Texas'), 'TX');`  Would you like to answer ? and then I mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP based on your image, your `replace()` function is trying to match something like..

`Puerto Rico` ..which is the value in the database, with..

`(Puerto Rico)`  ..which is the value you're telling it to match in the second argument of your `replace()` function.

Remove the `(` and the `)` from the second argument in your `replace()` calls, so they look like this..

`REPLACE(state_name, 'Puerto Rico', 'PR')`

..and I expect it will work. Basically the `replace()` function is working, it just isn't happening because the patterns it's looking for don't exist to match against.

**Don't over look the potential for "dirty data".**

In some cases—many cases—and apparently in this case, based on the comments, data values are not as clean as we would like and we need to condition them a little for the patterns to match as expected. Frequently, whitespace like spaces, tabs, and even carriage returns are the culprit, because at a glance we cannot perceive them. Secondly, character case (i.e. lower case, upper case) can prevent string value matching. So knowing this, if a seemingly obvious pattern is not matching as we might expect, the low-hanging fruit is to remove white space and eliminate character case mismatches. The following will remove leading and trailing spaces in the record data and force everything to upper case prior to testing the replace pattern supplied:

`REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(state_name))), UPPER('Puerto Rico'), 'PR')`

Note that this will not catch tabs or carriage returns! If you have more complex whitespace, you'll need to do a little more research. Start with [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/182486/57156) to a similar question over at dba.stack or perhaps the discussion noted [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-trim-function/) under the heading "Removing whitespace characters from a string".